# Home page not loading after editing header.php file

Tags: templates

My sites home page has lost all the content after i added a line of code for Google Analytics-Global tag in the header.php file. I took the backup of the file before i did the change and have restored it as well but issue is still there.

All other pages of the site are working fine, on the home page all i am seeing is site header and footer. My site us built using wordpress and Divi theme.

Please let me know what i can do to fix this.

Thanks
Mo

Comment: Try clearing cache of your website. You can also check if cache is enabled by hosting provider. Also you can add any tag to header from Divi theme settings. They have already blocks to add content to header so there is no need to modify header.php file.

Comment: Thanks Ahmer for your reply. Yes, I have cleared the cache and my site is hosted using aws lightsail wordpress bitnami hosting. Anything else i can try pls?

Comment: Why not include the code of your header.php in case there's something in there still triggering this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have lost the homepage content. Edit the page and restore the last revision as explained here.
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-the-wordpress-revision-history-feature

Comment: Thanks Ahmer, this did the trick!